# How to use headphones for giving input in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, microphone

[My headphones are detected for giving output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjj6i.png)

[Here my headphone is Not detected in input which having inbuilt Mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MrSf.png)

I have to record audio through my headphones in simple screen recorder.In simple screenrecorder it shows the error,

[JACKInput::Init] Error: Could not connect to JACK!
[PageRecord::StartPage] Error: Something went wrong during initialization.

It records the video fine but i cant record my audio along with it

Comment: A headphone is usually an output-device unless it has a built in microphone.

Comment: Ya it s having built in microphone.My headphone model-Sony XB450 AP @mook765